Disk full during dist upgrade
During dist upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 my disk got full and I see a lot of errors on terminal
Finally I reached: Upgrade complete
The upgrade has completed but there were errors during the upgrade process.
And I clicked close
Now do I reboot or I need to free some space and rerun trh upgrade again before rebooting?

The apt dist-upgrade command will not upgrade a system from one release to another; there is do-release-upgrade command that does that.  You should have ensured you had space BEFORE attempted the release-upgrade. We currently have few specifics; is this a Server install? Desktop install? how far in the upgrade were you (if downloading you can do whatever you want, if package installs had started you may have a problem, so be specific as to what exactly you saw! and what last few packages were & errors that occurred & be precise) etc..

Now everything fails with fatal error in libgcrypt apt, reboot etc.. It's desktop not server

Where in the question does it say it is an encrypted system? Please use the edit feature and add some more details to the question.
